# Typeahead in Bootstrap Tags input plug in not working

Tags: jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I am trying to use Bootstrap Tags Input (http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) in a small test application. I would like to use the typeahead function but cant seem to get it working. It appears to me like I have everything in order but I just cant seem to get the typeahead to work. Note that I am using this in Django - the bootstrap.min.js loads up in my base.html file. I am new to jquery so I'm sure I'm screwing up something in my script.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Testing{% endblock %}
{% block extra_head %}

    <link href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/snippets.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
    <link href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script>
     $('#tagtest').tagsinput({
        typeahead: {
        source: ['Amsterdam','Denver']
        }
      });
</script>
    {% endblock %}


{% block base_content %}

<input id ="tagtest" data-role="tagsinput" type="text"  value="Amsterdam,Washington"/>

{% endblock %}
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated/
TJS

Comment: Can you please tell us, if there's any error?

Comment: Also which version of *bootstrap* and *bootstrap tags* do you use?

Comment: There's no error being reported, its just a lack of the typeahead. The input is being properly formatted as tags and looks great, but theres no suggestions. 

For Bootstrap I am using version 2.32 and for bootstrap tags I don't see a version in the code, but I used the download that's in the link in my initial post. I did not use the version posted for Bootstrap V3

Comment: Actually I was able to figure it out. I was putting the script in the head of the page. I dropped it down right below the input and its working as needed. I don't know enough about Jquery to understand why - but I'll take it at this point and go back read why.

Comment: I think you should wrap your inline script with [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) and the head version should work as well.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone struggling with getting typeahead to work when working with Bootstrap 2.x: if you attach tagsinput to your input element by its id, so like:

```
$('#tagtest').tagsinput({...});
```

then DON'T set a **data-role="tagsinput"** on your input element.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bootstrap 3 this can be normal because typeahead has been removed. 
Add this typeahead js file [Link to typeahad version which works with bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js)